# Need help for building a state machine / transition system in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, state-machine

Edit : Not a duplicate since I seek the explanation of how i implement CTL and a model checking sequence.

I'm programming a model checker in java but im stuck in designing the transition system. An object of type (int, bool, string[] or set, int[] or set) is supposed to be added to a list of states, being the transition system. It supposed to be printing the list of states and transitions like (statenumber, bool, string[] transition, new int[] state). Right now is printing only the transition object and some memoryid i guess. Looks like this : Transition@11abc1234. My question is which further improvements shall I implements to make it print (int, bool, string[] or set, int[] or set) ? Thanks in advance! Here is my code :`import java.util.*;

public class TS 
{

```
private int i;
private boolean bool;
private static List<Transition> transitions;
State initial;
private int[] state;

TS(State initial, boolean bool, List<Transition> transitions, int[] state) 
{
    this.initial = initial;
    this.bool = bool;
    TS.transitions = transitions;
    this.state = state;
}

public State getNextState(Set<Condition> conditions) {
        for(Transition transition : transitions) {
            //boolean currentStateMatches = transition.old.equals(initial);
            //boolean conditionsMatch = transition.accepted.equals(accepted);
            if(Transition.from.equals(initial) && Transition.conditions.equals(conditions) 
                     ) {
                return transition.to;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    transitions = new Transition(1, true,  new String[] {"v"}, new int[] {2});
    transitions = new Transition(2, false, new String[] {"v"}, new int[] {1, 4});
    transitions = new Transition(3, false, new String[] {"c"}, new int[] {3});
    transitions = new Transition(4, false, new String[] {"c"}, new int[] {4});
    System.out.println(transitions);
}
```

}

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class Transition implements List {

```
 private int i;
private boolean b;
private String[] strings;
private int[] js;

public Transition(int i, boolean b, String[] strings, int[] js) {
    this.i = i;
    this.b = b;
    this.strings = strings;
    this.js = js;
}
public static State from;
 public static Set<Condition> conditions;
 public State to;

@Override
public boolean add(Transition e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void add(int index, Transition element) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Transition> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Transition> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void clear() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public Transition get(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public Iterator<Transition> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public ListIterator<Transition> listIterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public ListIterator<Transition> listIterator(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public Transition remove(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public Transition set(int index, Transition element) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public List<Transition> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}

import java.util.*;

public class State 

    {
    String state;
    }


public class Condition {
    String condition;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Not really, since i search further explanation of how i build the total statemachine.

Comment: Yes really -- it's a major part of your question, and you shouldn't have two-part questions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a method to your `Transition` class with the signature:

```
public String toString(){
  ...
}
```

The default `toString()` implementation (in the `Object` class) just prints out the name of the class and an internal reference. You can have your `toString()` print out whatever you want.